# AngularJS How to open a modal popup

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am brand new to AngularJS and I can't figure out how to open a modal dialog.  It's making me nuts!  Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  My controller code is below:

updated code:

buttonh:

```
<button class="btn default-btn advancedbtn" ng-click="vm.openModal()">Advanced</button>

 angular.module('crm.ma').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.openModal = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'topnav_advancedmodal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };



});
```

plunker link:  http://plnkr.co/edit/MeUnAqQf1FLHMhVJ8cGI?p=catalogue

Comment: Could you create a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/)

Comment: `$modal` is part of the ui.bootstrap package.  is that included in your project?  i.e. do you have `angular.module('crm.ma', ['ui.bootstrap']);` declared anywhere?

Comment: @Claies it is included in the project.

Comment: @kostbone I've created one here http://plnkr.co/edit/MeUnAqQf1FLHMhVJ8cGI?p=catalogue  I've never used plnkr before so I hope I did it right.  Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `modalInstance.result...` part of your code. It is useful when you need to get a result from a modal, but that's not your case, plus `modalInstance` is not defined in your code, so I guess you have an error with that. Also remove the `size` property from the `$modal.open`, as it's optional and as you didn't pass it in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ngDialog at https://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/

Dialogs in web applications are bit different than in desktop applications and the edge cases are many. ngDialog does a good job of solving many of these issues in one nice package.

Comment: unfortunately I have to do it this way.  I have to follow an example I already have, but I'm so new to angular that I don't know how to translate what I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };



});
```

Comment: I've copied your code only changing what I needed for my application and it still won't open on a button click.  I updated my code in the question.  Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: copy/paste all your code here for check whats wrong, also you can see more details if open the developer console in your browser. I recommended Chrome Browser.